# Destroy Activity after leaving it

Tags: kotlin, android-activity, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I need to destroy an activity that have fragments with the login methods when i go to the mainactivity. I already tried flags, supportfragmentmanager but didn't works. Please, if anyone know how to do this tell me, please!

The signIn fragment is inside the AuthenticationActivity
Going to MainActivity Code:

```
val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
             startActivity(intent)
```

When i go to the MainActivity, i need destroy the entire AuthenticationActivity, beucause i don't need that the users do login because they are already logged.

Comment: after startActivity you can call finish()

Comment: the finish dont work because the startactivity are inside an fragment

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple to achieve. Just call `finish` after launching the intent.

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
finish() //this will destroy the activity immediately
```

EDIT:
As you're inside a fragment, you need your activity to handle your call. To do so, call:

```
requireActivity().finish()
```

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finish())

Comment: the finish dont work because the startactivity are inside an fragment

Comment: @AntonyLajes then simply do `activity.finish()` from the fragment

Comment: keeps not working :(. I really dont know how i can destroy it, im searching but everything dont work properly

Comment: @AntonyLajes Well, you didn't mention that. Nonetheless, you got a bit of the answer. All you need to do is pass the context. You can pass this as the context such as ``context``.finish()

Comment: I've made an edit. Please try it.

Comment: @esQmo_ There is no `Context.finish()` function. Your `requireContext().finish()` code is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `finish()` on the Activity immediately after starting the other. To get the Activity instance in a Fragment, call `requireActivity()`.

```
val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
requireActivity().finish()
```